# Efficient way of creating array of array using an array and associative array in php

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an array like this:

```
$word=['total','sales']
```

and an associative array like this:

```
$tot = ['1'=>array('count','total','num of','no of', 'no. of'),
        '2'=>array('count')];
```

1 means it can be used before

2 means it can be used after

I have to replace the word that is present in both $word and $tot, and change that word with all other words that are there in $tot. The position is determined by the above rule.

I want all the combinations in an array of array like this:

```
[['count', 'sales'],
['sales', 'count'],
['total', 'sales'],
['num of', 'sales'],
['no. of', 'sales'],
['no of', 'sales']]
```

Is there any efficient way to do this in PHP?

PS:- If the $word variable is any of these the output should be the same:-

```
['count','sales']
['sales','count']
['no of','sales']
```

PS2:- Basically if the $word is any of the element of the output array. I want all other elements in the output array.

Comment: Why doesn't your output array include any values associated with the word `total` in `$word`?

Comment: @Nick It is there. Total sales

Comment: But why does `total` not combine with all the words in `$tot`?

Comment: @Nick Because it is there in associative array. I have to change the word that is there in associative array with all others in associative array.

Comment: @Nick Actually in the question I have not mentioned earlier. Now I have added it in question.

Comment: @Nick Can you please answer this question as Jeto has deleted his answer. Also, please check the minor modification in question.

Comment: This is pretty confusing. Can you add more examples and bit of explanation for the desired output?

Comment: @vivek_23 I have added the explaination.

Comment: Are there always only two words in `$words`?

Comment: @Nick There can be more than 2 words. But the keywords(words that are in $tot, eg.-count) can only be the first or last element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that I think will do what you want. It takes a list of words and a list of synonyms. The first and last words are processed and if they exist in the list of synonyms are replaced (either at the beginning or the end of the string, dependent on the index into the synonyms array).

```
function swap_words($words, $synonyms) {
    $all_synonyms = array_unique(array_merge(...$synonyms));

    $result = [];
    $word = $words[0];
    if (in_array($word, $all_synonyms)) {
        foreach ($synonyms[1] as $replacement) {
            $result[] = "$replacement " . implode(' ', array_slice($words, 1));
        }
        foreach ($synonyms[2] as $replacement) {
            $result[] = implode(' ', array_slice($words, 1)) . " $replacement";
        }
    }

    $c = count($words) - 1;
    $word = $words[$c];
    if (in_array($word, $all_synonyms)) {
        foreach ($synonyms[1] as $replacement) {
            $result[] = "$replacement " . implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, $c));
        }
        foreach ($synonyms[2] as $replacement) {
            $result[] = implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, $c)) . " $replacement";
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Usage:

```
$words = ['no of', 'autumn', 'sales'];
$tot = ['1'=>array('count','total','num of','no of', 'no. of'),
        '2'=>array('count')];
print_r(swap_words($words, $tot));

$words = ['autumn', 'sales', 'count'];
print_r(swap_words($words, $tot));
```

In both cases the output is

```
Array (
  [0] => count autumn sales
  [1] => total autumn sales
  [2] => num of autumn sales
  [3] => no of autumn sales
  [4] => no. of autumn sales
  [5] => autumn sales count
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/29pku)